# Not getting JSON response - Linkedin Company Rest API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

Not getting JSON response for Following [LinkedIn Company page Rest API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages)

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/num-followers?format=json
```

Here is example:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/289891/num-followers?format=json&oauth2_access_token=XXXXX
```

Getting following response as just a integer

```
14134
```

But API documentation states response is JSON as

```
{
  "num-followers": 10910
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a documentation error that has since been corrected.  The expected response is a plain integer value, as you are receiving.